# IllegalArgumentException when sorting file-array using mofify date on JDK1.7

Tags: java, sorting, java-7

I am having some problems sorting an array of files on a Java 7 virtual machine. Sometimes I get IllegalArgumentException from TimSort complaining about "Comparison method violates its general contract!". The comparator is relatively simple:

```
final File[] filesList = importDirectory.listFiles();
Arrays.sort(filesList, new Comparator<File>() {
    public int compare(File f1, File f2) {
        return Long.valueOf(f1.lastModified()).compareTo(f2.lastModified());
    }
});
```

What's wrong with this implementation? And why doesn't it fail on a Java 6 VM (I have read, that the TimSort Algorithm used in Java 7 is more restrictive, than the normal Merge sort of Java 6, but I still can't see where I'm violating the comparator contract.

Chris

Comment: Side note: you can replace `Long.valueOf(f1.lastModified()).compareTo(f2.lastModified())` with a slightly more efficient: `f1.lastModified() - f2.lastModified()`

Comment: No, you actually can’t, because lastModified() returns a `long` and `compare` has to return an `int`. You would have to clamp the resulting difference as it might well be greater (or smaller) than the available range for `int`s.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This would break of one of the files is modified when you are sorting it.

One way to make this faster (as lastModified is expensive) and avoid this issue is to build a Map of modification dates.

```
Map<File, Long> lastModifiedMap =
```

Comment: Well in my case the files are in a directory and the application is started. Initially I have to sort the files to process the oldest files first. So I doubt that this is the reason for it failing. But thanks for the optimization tip :-)

Comment: Ok ... Turns out you were right. My code was executed by a Spring MethodInvokingJobDetailFactoryBean which was triggered by a Quartz timer. Unfortunately it seems that the job was executing more than once if the execution time took more than 10 seconds. In this case I was trying to sort an Array for which some files have been moved by a parallell job. I added the "concurrent=false" to my spring configuration and the thing is running nicely ... and thanks to your optimiziation even a bit faster than before :-) ... thanks Peter :-)